# Draw ellipse and rounded rectangle in GEF eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse-gef

I want to draw an ellipse and a rounded rectangle in GEF editor.
I am not using Canvas and am using XY layout.I am able to draw rectangle in this layout but not the other two.

Please guide

Answer (score 1):

To draw a rounded rectangle you need to extend `Figure` and inside this figure draw a rectangle with rounded borders

(**Disclaimer** - This is a reduced version of the code I use for a rounded rectangle [here](https://github.com/vainolo/Object-Process-Programming/blob/master/com.vainolo.phd.opp.editor/src/com/vainolo/phd/opp/editor/figure/OPPStateFigure.java). Pretty sure it will work but I didn't test it)

```
public class RoundedRectangle extends Figure {
    private final RoundedRectangle rectangle;

    public RoundedRectangle() {
        super();
        setLayoutManager(new XYLayout());
        rectangle = new RoundedRectangle();
        rectangle.setCornerDimensions(new Dimension(20, 20)); // This is where the rounding happens
        // Anything else you want to customize
        add(rectangle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintFigure(Graphics graphics) {
        Rectangle r = getBounds().getCopy();
        setConstraint(rectangle, new Rectangle(0, 0, r.width, r.height));
    }
}
```